# How to return recently played song from Shoutcast server using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, shoutcast

I am trying to get songs history from Shoutcast server using PHP and JQuery. I have performed an ajax call to a php file that contains the code for getting recent played songs from streaming server.The Jquery is written within my application folder

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://example.com/recent_songs.php",
        headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            return false;
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
            console.log("Network Error!");
        }
    });
```

The PHP file is residing on a different server from that of Jquery file.

PHP (recent_songs.php):

```
$handle = '';
$handle = get_data();

function get_data() {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0' );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);

        $data_string = "";
        function write_function($handle, $data) {
            global $data_string;
            $data_string .= $data;
            if (strlen($data_string) > 200) {
              return 0;
            }
            else {
              return strlen($data);
             }
         }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ip:port/played.html');
        $data = curl_exec($ch);         
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);          
        if ($code!='200'){
            return 'error';
        }else{
            return 'success';           
}
```

It is always returning http code 0 and empty response from shoutcast server. However when I run this url in browser: `ip:port/played.html` It shows complete songs history there. Is there any idea to get response from shoutcast server.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: presumably `ip:port` are just placeholders and you are actually using an ip address and a port number?

Comment: Yes I am actually using ip address and port number for shoutcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Frisky Radio */
$ip='50.7.64.226';
$port=8000;

function get_data( $ip=false, $port=false ) {
    try{
        if( $ip && $port ){
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{$ip}:{$port}/played.html" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0' );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);

            $data=(object)array(
                'response'  =>  curl_exec($ch),
                'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo($ch)
            );

            return $data;
        }

        throw new Exception('Ip address and port number are required');
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}


$data=get_data( $ip, $port );
if( $data->info->http_code==200 ){
    echo '<pre>',print_r( $data->response,true ),'</pre>';
}
```

The output of the above ( slightly edited ) is:

```
02:09:28    FRISKY | RPO Records Session - March 2017 - Oscar Vasquez   Current Song
01:09:29    FRISKY | Rogue - July 2017 - Amber Long
00:09:32    FRISKY | Feelin FRISKY - June 2017 - Strachan
22:06:31    FRISKY | Voyager - July 2017 - Deepsense
20:02:07    FRISKY | Fatalist - July 2017 - Digital Department
18:00:47    FRISKY | 6th Auditorium - July 2017 - Andrea Cassino
17:02:07    FRISKY | Perspectives - July 2017 - Paul Kardos
16:02:11    FRISKY | Perspectives - July 2017 - Darin Epsilon
15:06:33    FRISKY | Hazendonk FM - July 2017 - Paul Hazendonk
14:03:26    FRISKY | Southside - July 2017 - Graziano Raffa
```

Alternatively, with the response data you could use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to grab the table displaying the data and use within page somewhere.
So, with the response:

```
/* Not all shoutcast servers have a list of played songs */
$table='No results';

$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $data->response );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//table[2]');


if( !empty( $col ) ){
    $doc=new DOMDocument();
    $doc->appendChild( $doc->importNode( $col->item( 0 ),true ) );
    $table=$doc->saveHTML();
}

$dom = $doc = $xp = $col = null;

echo $table;
```

Comment: I have tried the code you provided. But in both cases (mine and yours) curl_exec() is returning false on my server and it is returning http_code 0 even all options are same. Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: what ip/port are your trying to reach? Is it one on the interwebs or a local server?

Comment: I am using a real time ip and port to connect to shoutcast. yes it is on interweb

Comment: can you add the shoutcast server ip/port or is it sensitive?

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider, that was my server's issue regarding configurations. I put it on other server and it worked there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it's fixed - perhaps though you ought to mark the question resolved or delete it?

Comment: @Amandeep kaur Can you explain what issue you had with server?  I am getting exactly the same empty response as yours.